# How can I sort a two-dimensional array by length in PHP?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array of strings that I want to sort in order of descending length.  However, it is a two dimensional array and I'm not sure how to implement a function which will do what I want.

Here is an example of the array:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => "abc"
      [1] => "def"
      [2] => "1234"
    )

  [1] => Array
    (
      [0] => "ghijkl"
      [1] => "092"
      [2] => "234234"
    )

  [2] => Array
    (
      [0] => "mn"
      [1] => "opq"
      [2] => "67843"
    )
)
```

I'm only interested in the length of the first item in the sub-arrays.  So ideally it will end up looking like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [0] => "ghijkl"
      [1] => "092"
      [2] => "234234"
    )
  [1] => Array
    (
      [0] => "abc"
      [1] => "def"
      [2] => "1234"
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
      [0] => "mn"
      [1] => "opq"
      [2] => "67843"
    )
)
```

Cheers for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
usort($array, function ($a, $b) { return strlen($b[0]) - strlen($a[0]); });
```

(uses PHP 5.3 syntax)

Comment: This is great, except it returns the array from short to long when I want it the other way.  Thanks though, I can do that much myself!

Comment: @Nick Then simply swap the `$a` and `$b` arguments around.

Comment: This answer helped me, but I wanted to sort by the length of the entire sub-array so I did this `usort($arr, function ($a, $b) { return count($a) - count($b); });`

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$your_array = array
(
  array
    (
      "abc",
      "def",
      "1234"
    ),

  array
    (
      "ghijkl",
      "092",
      "234234"
    ),
array
    (
      "mn",
      "opq",
      "67843"
    )
);

function customSort(Array $a, Array $b){         
     return strlen($b[0]) - strlen($a[0]);  
}

usort($your_array, 'customSort');
var_dump($your_array);
```

Comment: This won't work correctly. `<` will return `true` or `false`. The comparison function is supposed to return `0`, a value `< 0` or a value `> 0` though.

Comment: It does work though, because PHP will evaluate false to 0 and true to 1.

Comment: Yes, but that means you can't represent the "smaller than" case correctly, which *may* cause the sort order to be incorrect/undefined.